Mostrar archivo .pdf en IFrame desde OneDrive o GoogleDrive
Muy buenas,
Estoy creando una aplicación web muy sencilla con ASP.NET en la que se puede navegar por unos directorio y al seleccionar un archivo, se consulta de BBDD para obtener su URL en OneDrive o GoogleDrive y mostrarlo en un IFrame.
Los archivos están compartidos con cualquiera que tenga el enlace y estoy generando el enlace desde la opción de "Insertar archivo" que te genera directamente todo el código del IFrame.
El problema es que con words y otros archivos me funciona perfectamente, pero cuando intento mostrar un pdf me salta una excepción que además no da información. A ver si alguien sabe qué puede estar pasando.
Declaración del IFrame:
<div class="content">
    <div class="iframe-container">
        <iframe id="fileViewer" scr="" Allowfullscreen></iframe>             
    </div>
</div>

Luego tengo un jsTree desde donde relleno el src cuando se consulta la API para un documento:
    .on('click', '.jstree-anchor', async function () {

        var nodeId = $(this).closest('.jstree-node').attr('id');

        if (!nodeId.startsWith("D")) {
            var newUrl = await $.get("Files/OpenFile/" + nodeId);

            document.getElementById('fileViewer').src = newUrl;
        }                 

    })

Se carga la primera página del archivo pero no consigue mostrar más y salta esta excepción que no da mucha información, o no sé interpretarla:

En cambio si uso una URL proporcionada por sitio de pago como pdfdeck.com no tengo ningún problema en abrir el archivo pdf, por lo que entiendo que el problema está más en como accedo a los archivos en la nube que en mi propia aplicación, que es muy sencilla.
Como he comentado tengo los archivos compartidos con cualquier persona y acceso desde las URL generadas para lo IFrames directamente. Alguien a tenido algún problema parecido? También he probado con la etiqueta embed y no funciona.
Muchas gracias,
un saludo.
